# Solving $2^x - 3^x + 6^x =0$.

Tags: exponential-function, systems-of-equations, problem-solving

Are there any known methods to solve
$$2^x - 3^x + 6^x = 0,$$ where $x$ is either in closed form, perhaps in terms of special functions, or to give inequalities on the answers, where $x\in\mathbb{C}$ ?

My thoughts: $x\in\mathbb{C}$ would presumably lead to many solutions. My first attempt was the following:

$$e^{x\log 2}-e^{x\log 3}+e^{x\log 6}=0.$$ Letting $x=a+ib$ then gives the two equations

$$2^a\cos(b\log 2)-3^a\cos(b\log 3)+6^a\cos(b\log 6)=0$$
and
$$2^a\sin(b\log 2)-3^a\sin(b\log 3)+6^a\sin(b\log 6)=0,$$
corresponding to the real and imaginary parts respectively. From then on it gets a bit messy. My feeling is there are no known methods except numerical ones?

Comment: note that $6^x=2^x\cdot 3^x$ so you have to solve $a-b+ab=0$

Comment: To solve: $2^{-x}=1+3^{-x}$. No real solution (easy). Two pairs of conjugate complex solutions. Numerical values available from a plethora of online tools. And so what?

Comment: @Did [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5Ex-3%5Ex%2B6%5Ex+%3D0) claims that there are 4 pairs of conjugate solutions.

Comment: @Surb This is odd, I fed `solve 2^x=1+3^x` into WA and got only 4...

Comment: @Did you originally stated $-x $ in the exponents... maybe that's it? On the move so can't check...

Comment: @pbs Irrelevant.

Comment: @Surb And "your" solutions forget one pair of "mine"... Hurray for WA! :-)

Comment: @Did I get $2^x-3^x+6^x = 0 \iff 2^x(1+3^x)=3^x \iff 1+3^x=(3/2)^x$ and not the equation you got. But when I give $1+3^x=(3/2)^x$ to wolfram I get 2 solutions... (so the other might come in the case $2^x=0$...)

Comment: @Surb Multiply your equation with $3^{-x}$ and you get Did's.

Comment: @Did :) I always believed WA was reliable.... well I'll reconsider my thoughts ;).

Comment: @DanielFischer right thanks :). But it is wierd that all these equations that are supposed to be equivalent outputs different solutions...

Comment: @Surb $3^x=2^x+6^x$, divide by $6^x$, thus $2^{-x}=1+3^{-x}$. // Upon relexion, I think all three first pairs of solutions in "your" WA feed are phony (the ones with huge real parts).

Comment: @Surb "I always believed WA was reliable" Seriously? I thought that the opposite was well known...

Comment: @Did This shows then that I still have a lot to learn :) (that's also one of the main reason of my presence here). BTW: what do you mean by "phony" solution? I mean what makes you believe that they aren't really solutions of the equation?

Comment: @Surb Yep. All the same, I would be interested in having some detailed explanations about WA erratic behaviour in the present case (being nearly completely ignorant about these matters, I cannot provide them myself).

Comment: @Did Assuming that $a^x$ is interpreted as $\exp(x\log a)$ with the real logarithm of $a > 0$, an easy estimate of the moduli shows that $\lvert \operatorname{Re} x\rvert \leqslant 1$ for all solutions, so the ones with huge real part are then bogus. You can maybe get solutions with large real part if a non-real value of the logarithm is used.

Comment: @Surb "Phony": I alluded to the reason in my previous comment: those $x$ have huge positive real parts hence $2^{-x}$ and $3^{-x}$ are so close to $0$ that their difference cannot be $1$ (as it should).

Comment: @DanielFischer Yup, the reason I had in mind when I wrote they were phony (=false solutions).

Comment: @DanielFischer Hmmm, indeed if $2^{u+iv}$ is taken as being $$\exp((u+iv)(\ln2+2ni\pi))=2^ue^{-2n\pi v}e^{i(v\ln2+2nu\pi)}$$ for some random integer $n$, and the same for $3^{u+iv}$, then strange things may happen. Might be the explanation of WA extraneous results (but not of the missing ones!).

Comment: Let $y=e^x$ , then solve for roots of , $y^{\ln \frac32} - y^{\ln 3}=1 $ ?

Comment: @Mann No thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equations like this have infinitely many complex solutions.

Let $a = \log 2-\log 3$ and $b = \log 6 - \log 3 = \log 2$. Then let $f(z) = \exp(az) + \exp(bz)$. We want to solve $f(z)=1$

Since the two coefficients are real and have opposite signs, for $\Re(z) \to \infty$, $f(z) \sim \exp(bz)$ and for $\Re(z) \to - \infty$, $f(z) \sim \exp(az)$.

In fact, if you note $r_+$ the positive real solution to $\exp(bx) = \exp(ax) +1$ and $r_-$ the negative real solution to $\exp(ax) = \exp(bx) + 1$ (in fact, it is $-1$), all the solutions to $f(z) = 1$ must be in the region $r_- \le \Re(z) \le r_+$

Then the number of solutions with $|\Im(z)| < B$ is the number of turns around $1$ made by $f(z)$ as you go along the rectangle whose vertices are $r_\pm \pm iB$
(more precisely, it's $\frac 1{2i\pi} \int f'/(f-1) dz$)

On the right side of the rectangle, $f$ is homotopic to $\exp(bz)$ without going through the disk, so the integral is $2ibB + O(1)$

On the left side, same thing except we go downwards, so we get $-2iaB + O(1)$.

Summing up everything, assuming the top and bottom integrals are also a $O(1)$, the number of $1$s with $|\Im(z)| < B$ is $\frac{(b-a)B}\pi + O(1) = \frac {B\log 3} \pi + O(1)$ .

---

For a more detailed analysis,

let $H(x) = a$ for $x<0$ and $H(x) = b$ for $x>0$, and define

$I(y_1,y_2) = \int_{\Bbb R} \left(\frac {a\exp(a(z-iy_1)) + b\exp(b(z-iy_2))}  {\exp(a(z-iy_1)) + \exp(b(z-iy_2)) - 1} - H(z)\right) dz$.

Since the integrand converges to $0$ exponentially at $\pm \infty$, this integral is well-defined whenever the integrand doesn't have a pole,
which means whenever we don't find a solution to the shifted equation on the real line. Away form those solutions, $I$ is even holomorphic asa function of two complex variables.

Moreover, if $dt > 0$ is real, then a change of variables gives
 $I(y_1+idt,y_2+idt) = \int_{\Bbb R} \left(\frac {a\exp(a(z-iy_1+dt)) + b\exp(b(z-iy_2+dt))}  {\exp(a(z-iy_1+dt)) + \exp(b(z-iy_2+dt)) - 1} - H(z) \right) dz
 \\ = \int_{\Bbb R} \left(\frac {a\exp(a(z-iy_1)) + b\exp(b(z-iy_2))} {\exp(a(z-iy_1)) + \exp(b(z-iy_2)) - 1} - H(z-dt)\right) dz
 \\ = I(y_1,y_2) + \int_{\Bbb R} (H(z) - H(z-dt)) dz
 \\ = I(y_1,y_2) + \int_0^{dt} (b-a)dz
 \\ = I(y_1,y_2) + (b-a)dt$

Since this is true for all positive real $dt$ and $I$ is holomorphic, 
it is also valid for any complex $dt$ (as long as we don't go over a solution),
replacing $dt$ with $-idt$ gives us $I(y_1+dt,y_2+dt) = I(y_1,y_2) + i(a-b)dt$.

Moreover, as a function of two real variables, $I$ is $2\pi/a$-periodic in the first and $2\pi/b$-periodic in the second,
so we only need a nice picture of $I$ on a fundamental rectangle. 
And to do this we need the picture of where the integral jumps (by $2i\pi$) because of a solution to the shifted equation.

Let $x \in \Bbb R$. A solution at $z=x$ happens when $1 = \exp(a(x-iy_1)) + \exp(b(x-iy_2))$.
With the triangle inequality and the law of cosines, this is only possible when $x \in [r_- ; r_+]$
with $2\exp(ax)\cos(ay_1) = 1 + \exp(2ax) - \exp(2bx), 2\exp(ax)\cos(by_2) = 1 + \exp(2bx) - \exp(2ax), \sin(ay_1)\sin(by_2) \le 0$.

Plotting those points give this graphics :

[image]

Finding a solution at $x+iy$ to the original problem is equivalent to reaching a discontinuity (so reaching one of the black curves) at $I(y,y)$. For example this shows that there are two solutions with imaginary part in $[0; 2\pi/b]$ because the diagonal crossed two curves so far.

Since $a/b$ is irrationnal, when we follow that diagonal using $I(y_1+dt,y_2+dy) = I(y_1,y_2) + i(a-b)dt$ and adding back $2i\pi$ whenever you cross the curve, the trajectory is dense in the corresponding torus, and therefore by continuity, $I$ is determined by this up to an additive constant.

In fact, now we can check that $I(y_1,y_2) = I(0,0) + iay_1 - iby_2 \mod (2i\pi)$. So $I$ was secretly a piecewise affine function ! (though as you input complex arguments, the black curve will change shape and you might have more complicated things happening, for example it might cross itself ... )

We also see that if we "approximate" the curves with straight lines, then the number of solutions we find with imaginary part between $0$ and $B$ would be exactly $\lfloor (b-a)B/\pi + k \rfloor$ for some constant $k$. For the actual equation, this is still $(b-a)B/\pi + O(1)$ and you can find the best lower and upper bound for the $O(1)$ by measuring precisely how far the curve gets away from the approximation line, and how far the origin is from the first line.

To find the distribution of the real part of the solutions, (so the expected number of roots with real part in some given interval in $[r_-,r_+]$), thanks to Weyl's equidistribution theorem you "only" need to highlight the points of the curves corresponding to that interval and see how much "shadow" they generate when you project them along the diagonal compared to the rest of the curve. This is a bunch of ugly calculus so I'll skip it.

Comment: At the moment I'm really not sure how to argue properly for the top and bottom integrals. If nobody chimes in I'll probably get back to it in a few days.

Comment: there may also be something to be said about the distribution of the real parts

Comment: great answer, thank you. Did you ever get chance to look at those integrals?

Comment: I've been thinking about them a few times but I'm sorry to say I've never been able to conclusively prove their boundedness. I should probably ask about it on another question. *is sorry* *cries*

Comment: If these integrals cannot be proved then does this mean there is still the possibility that the function is never equal to 1 ? Or does it mean simply that nothing can be said. Or perhaps that there are an infinite number of 1's ? Anyway thanks - I will attempt the integrals myself first.

Comment: I think I have a proof and with a few improvements it also determines explicitly the distribution of the real parts of the solutions. I will write it tomorrow. It is kinda beautiful.

Comment: only I don't know if it generalizes easily and I was hoping for something that worked the same for any number of exponentials.

Comment: i have edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you this will give me more than enough food for though :-D

Answer (score -1):

*The* four true and only solutions...

[image]

Comment: (-1) This is a link to Wolfram...no insight that isn't already one click away for an Op. Also directly contradicts another answer.

Comment: @NonStandard The reason why this is community. Re the OP, you might be missing the target here since the OP seemed to consider the explanation clarified things.